# Celery async task executed only once

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

So I have a task from which I call another task which sends email:

```
@app.task(name='login.sync.register')
def register(user_obj):
    result = user_service.register(user_obj)

    from .async import send_verification_email
    send_verification_email.delay(result['user']['id'])

    return result
```

The email sending task is:

```
@app.task(name='login.async.send_verification_email', bind=True, max_retries=3)
def send_verification_email(self, user_id):
    try:
        email_service.send_verification_email(user_id)
    except Exception as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc)
```

It works perfectly for the first time. The email gets send. When I call the register task second time, it succeeds but send_verification_email is not executed. I don't see anything in the logs.

Any idea why? When I restart the Celery worker, it sends email the first time but then stops sending emails after that.

Comment: Did you try rewriting register task with user_id like in send_verification_email and then loading it from db?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think it is a bad idea to use broad exception handlers like you do. except Exception as exc will hide any problems from you and you will never know - what is actually going on.

You can debug your code after removing async call and making it synchronous:

send_verification_email(result['user']['id'])

I will explain. You need to remove all .delay calls and call your tasks directly. And inside send_verification_email() task you can insert line

import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

to trace calls and watch the results of email_service.send_verification_email(user_id).

```
@app.task(name='login.async.send_verification_email', bind=True, max_retries=3)
def send_verification_email(self, user_id):
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    email_service.send_verification_email(user_id)
```

Also you can replace pdb with pudb which is little friendlier. You can install it with 'pip install pudb'

---

I cannot comment because I just registered and have no carma.